# How to set up a new Mule project from scratch (Maven configured)

Tags: maven, setup-project, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, new-project

I have recently started working with the Mule using AnypointStudios. Now I need to create a new, Maven base, Mule project. I never had to do this so I'm pretty lost on how to set up and create a proper Mule project with maven.
Someone can help me?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great that you are exploring Mulesoft. Good luck.

as per your question that you are new and want to create a new Mulesoft project. so I would like that you first got through this article https://dzone.com/articles/Step-by-step-guide-to-using-mule-esb that is written by me and will guide you set up and get ready for your first mule project.

after going through completely this article then create a new project new Project in Anypoint Studio

1. click on file-> create a new mule project as shown in the below screenshot
   [image]
2. now give your project name and select mule runtime, in my system I had only 4.3 so it is showing that otherwise, you can select by your choice (to install more runtime is another question)

[image]

3. now you will get your API with your pom file that will have all related dependencies. there you can add any dependency according to your requirement.

[image]

note: After all maven configuration check that at location **C:\Users\yourPCName\.m2** one folder will create, that contains one more folder named repository second one file need to create **settings.xml** that we will use if Access MuleSoft Enterprise Repository (for example need to access nexus Artifactory.

for example, attached below a sample of settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <servers>

    <server>
      <id>id</id>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>

    <server>
      <id>mulesoft-release-local</id>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>

  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>id</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>name</name>
      <url>URL of artifactory</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

</settings>
```

I hope this answer will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First if you have access to MuleSoft Enterprise Repositories you have to add the repositories to Maven [settings.xml](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/maven-reference#settings-xml-file) as indicated in the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/maven-reference#configure-maven-to-access-mulesoft-enterprise-repository

If you want to create a new Maven project the easiest way is to use Anypoint Studio. Studio 7.x (recommended) always creates Maven projects. For Studio 6.x you need to select the option when creating a project, or use a menu option to migrate to a Maven project after the project was created. It is in [Studio 6 Maven documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/6/using-maven-in-anypoint-studio).

Note that Studio 7.x is for Mule 4.x only, and Studio 6.x is for Mule 3.x only.